# How to add click event on element added by jquery append or prepend in angular 4

Tags: jquery, html, angular, typescript

I am working on a project and I have used fancy select for more attractive selector drop down option. I have appended the fancy select using jquery and now I want to listen to an click event form those appended select options. I thought of using jquery event handler but i can only write jquery code inside function for example inside appendOptions(){} or ngOnInit(){} but this will execute only when function is executed.

```
appendOptions(){
  this.categories = this.response.data.categories;  //this is response form api

  jQuery('.newSelect').prepend('<div class="selectedOption">Browse Categories</div><div class="newOptions"></div>'); //prepending the outer element

  for (let cat of this.categories) {
    jQuery('.newOptions').append('<div class="newOption" data-value="' + cat.id + '">' + cat.category + '</div>');  //appending options element
  }
  // i can write jquery code here 
}
// i cant write jquery here
```

I tried to user render2 of angular but I cant figure out the click of the options.  all the native element will fire this element.

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
      this.handleClick(event);
  })
}
```

How can I reference using element class or id and get their data values? I also tried using @ViewChild but I don't know how to add element reference (eg: #element) dynamically. And I am not being able to think what to use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're already using `jQuery` you could as well use jQuery to register an event handler. `this.elementRef.nativeElement` refers to the host element of the component, not some dynamically added HTML. You'd need `this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.newOptions').addEventListener(...)` or similar. `@ViewChild()` doesn't support dynamically added HTML.

Comment: the problem is i cant write jquery code outside function and when i write it inside function then it will not execute until the function is not executed

Comment: What exactly does "outside function" mean? Your question lacks context.

Comment: i mean typescript only allows jquery syntax inside a function not inside class

Comment: The put it inside a function like `ngOnInit` of `ngAfterViewInit` which gets called by Angular.

Comment: no luck i tried adding jquery click event listener on ngOnInit but it doesnot gets triggred

Comment: You probably did something wrong, but I can't tell because I have no way to investigate. If you could create a http://stackblitz.com example that allows to reproduce it would be easy.

Comment: Thanks i solved it actually the issue was the event listener was executed before appending element. it worked when i agai called onInit after appending element

Comment: Glad to hear . .